# Hive is removing decimals after cast?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

In Hive I was performing some tests with operations and got a behaviour that I could not understand.
While doing that operation, Hive is returning below results with 17 decimals after the comma:

```
select 500/3260;
> 0.15337423312883436
```

But when I am triyng to cast it with decimal format, the result is:

```
select cast(500 as decimal(38,18)) / cast(3260 as decimal(38,18));
> 0.153374
```

I would like to have 18 decimals, but only 6 are displayed.
Could you please explain me why it is giving this result?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to decimal division rules detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql). The link is for SQL server, but apparently the behaviour shown here is the same.

> The scale will be set to 6 if it's greater than 6 and if the integral part is greater than 32. In this case, both integral part and scale would be reduced and resulting type is decimal(38,6). Result might be rounded to 6 decimal places or the overflow error will be thrown if the integral part can't fit into 32 digits.

The SQL server implementation was referenced in this Hive [document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/27362075/Hive_Decimal_Precision_Scale_Support.pdf) (page 3).